# Python - Tkinter repeat function not working?

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I am trying to make a function that makes a circle in a random place, in return the first time it executes correctly but after that every time i try to execute it it doesn't work. Please help me and here's the code:

```
size = 200

class Spots():
    def __init__(self):
        self.avaible = True
    def taken(self):
        self.avaible = False

a1 = Spots()
a2 = Spots()
a3 = Spots()
b1 = Spots()
b2 = Spots()
b3 = Spots()
c1 = Spots()
c2 = Spots()
c3 = Spots()

spots = (a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,c1,c2,c3)

import random as r
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
cv = Canvas(tk, width = 200 + size * 3, height = 200 + size * 3)
cv.pack()

def tkO():
    rch = r.choice(spots)
    x = 100
    y = 100
    
    while a1.avaible == True or a2.avaible == True or a3.avaible == True or b1.avaible == True or b2.avaible == True or b3.avaible == True or c1.avaible == True or c2.avaible == True or c3.avaible == True:
        while rch.avaible == False:
            rch = r.choice(spots)
        break
    rch.taken
    if "a" in str(rch):
        y = 100
        if "1" in str(rch):
            x = 100
        if "2" in str(rch):
            x = 100 + size
        if "3" in str(rch):
            x = 100 + size * 2
    if "b" in str(rch):
        y = 100 + size
        if "1" in str(rch):
            x = 100
        if "2" in str(rch):
            x = 100 + size
        if "3" in str(rch):
            x = 100 + size * 2
    if "c" in str(rch):
        y = 100 + size * 2
        if "1" in str(rch):
            x = 100
        if "2" in str(rch):
            x = 100 + size
        if "3" in str(rch):
            x = 100 + size * 2

    cv.create_oval(x,y,x+size,y+size)
```

Any help will be appreciated. Also, if you can find a way to make the mess in the `tkO()` function more efficient (shorter) that will help too.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What does it do differently the second time? What have you done to debug it? Have you verified that the function is being called more than once? Have you checked the computations to see if it's computing different coordinates each time?

Comment: When I execute it through the Python Shell, in tk it doesn't do anything and I'm calling the function through Shell to see if everything is correct, although it isn't. I have tried several changes to fix some errors but at the end I have only 1 circle.

Comment: Are you certain  you only have one circle, or is it possible you're creating multiple identical circles? This seems like an easy thing for you to debug with just a couple of well-placed print statements.

Comment: One thing is certain, statements like if "a" in str(rch) won't do what you think they are doing. Are you aware that str(rch) will return something like '<__main__.Spots object at 0x10f534e20>'? "a", "b", and "c" will always be in that string?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I managed to fix the absolute mess with a brand new tuple and changing rch to rchobject, while rch being the string and it began to work properly! Thank you so much. I could not have done this without you.

Answer (score 1):

The function is fixed! All I had to do was add a few more variables, making the if statements with `if "(letter)" in rch being strings and the if statements with class objects - objects (rchobject).

Thanks to Bryan Oakley for helping me figure this out!

```
import random as r

spots = (a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,c1,c2,c3)
spotsStr = spots but with strings

def tkO():
 rn = r.randint(1,10)
 rch = spotsStr[rn]
 rchobject = spots[rn]
```